# Android 4.4.2 Accessibility Explore By Touch not working in app

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, talkback

I'm writing an app that behaves normally in Android 4.3 but does not in 4.4.2.   The issue is that with Accessibility "Talk Back" feature turned on you should be able to explore by touch over the buttons of your app and have it announce the contentDescription.

This works fine in 4.3 but in 4.4.2 only the navigation drawer and items on it announce themselves. The rest of the app is all buttons and a fragment on the main activity.

I should point out that the main activity uses TextToSpeech, I'm worried there is a new conflict here.

Has anyone else seen this problem?   Any suggestions on a solution?

Thanks, Chuck Brandt

Answer (score 0):

Is the content that is not being spoken in a WebView? Is the navigation drawer implemented via a DrawerLayout from the support library? If the latter is true, is the content announced when the navigation drawer is hidden (i.e. drawer closed)?

Comment: No the content is standard buttons in an entirely native app.  The drawer (which works normally) is implemented with DrawerLayout.  The buttons on the main activity, are not announced when the drawer is closed.   TalkBack does announce the selected drawer item when it is closed, but I think it does that in 4.3 as well.  Our major issue is that the buttons don't get announced.  I should note that we do get a vibrate and a click on the buttons in question, just no utterance of the android:contentDescription.

Comment: Just found out, unfortunately, that MotoG exhibits the same issue as our Nexus 4 phones.   I am going to start stripping features out of the build in an attempt to find out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue.  It seems to be related to the fact that I had a group of buttons on a fragment, I moved them into the activity.   I also had (temporarily) android:importantForAccessibility="noHideDescendants" in the outer LinearLayout, I removed it.  I was probably trying all settings of that flag and that is the last one I used.  Like I say, not sure which one was most important to getting it to work, but it is working now.   Thank you for all your help.  Chuck

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue, can you give some more details for your fix.